# Принять тело запроса POST и преобразовать данные в массив (не используя CURL)

Tags: php, битрикс

**Доброго времени суток**
Я принимаю данные тела в POST запросе таким методом: $entityBody = file_get_contents('php://input') 
Соответственно в $entityBody все данные в виде строк.
А в теле запроса, данные отправляются вот в таком виде:

```
{
"title": "My first POST request",
"body": "Content of my first POST request!",
"userId": 789
"status": 1
}

{
"title": "My first POST request",
"body": "Content of my first POST request!",
"userId": 790
"status": 0
}

{
"title": "My first POST request",
"body": "Content of my first POST request!",
"userId": 791
"status": 0
}
```

Мне нужно эти данные преобразовать в массив и пробегаться по ним foreach и в нем проверять каждый status.
Подскажите пожалуйста как все это реализовать?
Я пробовал методы php преобразования в массив строку, но получается не то что мне нужно.
Если что то не понятно в вопросе, то скажите, я подкорректирую.

Comment: больше поможет, если вы добавите в ответ результат var_export($entityBody)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
"title": "My first POST request",
"body": "Content of my first POST request!",
"userId": 791
"status": 0
}
```

Похож на json, только запятая пропущена, может Вы неправильно скопировали сюда
если бы была запятая то было бы так:

```
{
"title": "My first POST request",
"body": "Content of my first POST request!",
"userId": 791,
"status": 0
}
```

Тогда бы можно было бы преобразовать из json строки в массив и далее работать как с массивом, так:

```
$jsonStrArray = '{
    "title": "My first POST request",
    "body": "Content of my first POST request!",
    "userId": 791,
    "status": 0
}';

$array = json_decode($jsonStrArray, true);
```